select2 seleccionar automaticamente si solo hay un resultado
tengo un select2 que hace una petición Ajax y busca resultados, en la base de datos, y me gustaría que cuando solo hubiese un resultado me cogiera automáticamente esa opción.
$('.add_product').select2({
        
        ajax: {
          url: "/busca_productos",
          delay: 300,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                search: params.term,
                type: 'documentos_busqueda'
            }
            return query;
          },
          processResults: function (data) {
          
            var datos_busqueda = [];
            data.forEach((d)=> {
              datos_busqueda.push(
                { 
                  id: d.id, 
                  value:d.id, 
                  text: d.name, 
                  
                })
                              
            });
            return {
                results: datos_busqueda
            };
            
          }
        },
        
        cache: true,
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Buscar producto...',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        templateSelection: function (data, container) {
          $(data.element).attr('id', data.id);
          $(data.element).attr('value', data.id);
          $(data.element).attr('text', data.name);
        
          return data.text;
        },
        
      });

La idea es que, si la consulta me devuelve un resultado automáticamente seleccione ese valor, pero no consigo recoger ninguno.
Gracias.

Intenta con esto:
Haces la validacion del tamaño retornado de los datos obtenidos de la perición de tal manera que te quedaría así:
processResults: function (data) {

/* TU CODIGO .... */

if (datos_busqueda.length === 1) { //Verifica si retorna solo 1 resultado
    setTimeout(() => { //Espera a que se procesen los resultados
        $('.add_product').select2('trigger','select', { //Establece el valor de select2
            data: datos_busqueda[0]
        });
    }, 1); //tiempo de espera para que el select2 termine de procesar
}

return { ... };
}
},

/* resto de tu código */


Gracias por la respuesta, me ha funcionado.

@Atrus, si la respuesta te ayuda a solucionar tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada.
